# Javascript - Averaging values from array incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm attempting a coding exercise, and I can't seem to find the problem. I need to pull the median from an array. If the array is an even length, I need the average of two values.

```
const N = parseInt(readline());
var inputs = readline().split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const X = parseInt(inputs[i]);
}

var arr = inputs.sort((a, b) => a - b);
if (arr.length % 2 === 0)
{
    console.error(arr);
    console.error(arr[arr.length / 2 - 1]);
    console.error(arr[arr.length / 2]);
    var a = arr[arr.length / 2 - 1];
    var b = arr[arr.length / 2];
    var ans = (a + b) / 2;
    console.log(ans);
}
else console.log(arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)]);
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:
[ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' ]
5
6
28

So from the console output, my array is sorted properly. Next, I'm pulling out the two medians correctly. My **a** is indeed 5, and my **b** is indeed 6. But adding them with (a + b) / 2 suddenly turns into 28... Why?

Comment: because a and b is strings `56/2=28`

Comment: element in your arr is String. So "5"+"6" = "56" -> 56/2 = 28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables `a` and `b` are being treated as strings and concatenated, then the division happens: `'5'` + `'6'` becomes `56` and dividing them by `2` results in `28`. So you need to coerce them into numbers before doing the addition:

```
 var ans = (+a + +b) / 2;
```

Appending a arithmetic operator before the variables will coerce them into numbers and then you can add them.

Comment: Oh man, what an eye-opener for JavaScript (and coding practice in general). Thanks. I'll be more careful of this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

dude u are adding two strings i.e. '5' + '6' which makes it 56 divide by 2 = 28 (Yes JS is crazy). Just use parseInt,

```
var ans = (parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10)) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is seems you are adding Strings together. It is essentially taking the charCode rather than the Number value ex: `'1'.charCodeAt(0)`

I solved this by using .map on the Array of inputs:

```
const N = parseInt(readline());
var inputs = readline().split(' ').map(function(num) { return parseInt(num); });

var arr = inputs.sort((a, b) => a - b);
if (arr.length % 2 === 0)
{
    console.error(arr);
    console.error(arr[arr.length / 2 - 1]);
    console.error(arr[arr.length / 2]);
    var a = arr[arr.length / 2 - 1];
    var b = arr[arr.length / 2];
    var ans = (a + b) / 2;
    console.log(ans);
}
else console.log(arr[Math.floor(arr.length/2)]);
```